# The body of my Angular post request is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, express

So the body of my Angular post request is empty on my server. The post request from my client application is:

```
var data = {
      Stime: '+this.Stime+',
      Etime: '+this.Etime+',
      eAMPM: '+this.eAMPM+',
      sAMPM: '+this.sAMPM+',
      id: '+this.id+',
      activity: '+this.activity+',
      auto_insert: '+this.auto_insert+',
      yearmonthday: '+this.yearmonthday+',
      color1: '+this.c+'
   }
   this.$http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'http://localhost:3000/operation',
       data: JSON.stringify(data)
   })
```

before I tried using this post request I just had a very long query string and this passed the data just fine. But I am cleaning up my code now and this way isnt working. 
On my server I have:

```
app.post('/operation', function(req,res){
   console.log(req.body); //prints {}
   res.send("inserted");
});
```

Also on the server side I have

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
multer = require('multer'),
jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

app.use(jsonParser)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: Have you tried using angular $http?  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. Assemble the data object 
like you are doing and use `$http.post('http://localhost:3000/operation', data)`?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `app.post(...) {}` you need to wait for data to become available like this:

```
    var body = '';
    req.on('data',function(data) { body += data; });
    req.on('end', function(data) {
        req.body = JSON.parse(body);
        conosle.log(request.body);
    });
```